# Change URL of a folder in sharePoint list 2010

Tags: sharepoint, list, url

I want to change the URL of a folder in my SharePoint list 2010 to be more meaningful as it has %20 and all weird numbers generated in the URL which my employer doesn't like. I know how to change the name of a List but not sure about a folder in a list. How can I change the URL to be more meaningful and neat devoid of %20 and other useless characters?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link on how to modify the URL with SharePoint Designer. It's nice and easy.

[How to Change the Url For a SharePoint 2010 List or Library](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=52)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can rename the folder by [setting SPListItem["Name"]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/10/02/programmatically-rename-a-file-inside-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) to the new, more meaningful value, or you can leave the name the same, but change the [Folder's WelcomePage property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.welcomepage.aspx#Y537), as below.

The SharePoint Foundation API includes this example of setting the URL you are redirected to when you navigate to a folder.

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("http://MyServer/sites/MyWikiSite"))
{
    SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
    SPFolder oFolder = oWebsite.RootFolder; 
    oFolder.WelcomePage = "My Wiki Library/MyWelcome.aspx";
    oFolder.Update();
    oWebsite.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rename the folder, so that the new name does not contain spaces and special characters, %20 stands for space

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SharePoint Designer?

[Download it free](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx)